# Remove element of array of list type in c++

Tags: c++

I have the following code and I got an error during the run time, saying that iterator in not incremental. I want to remove the list items inside an array.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

struct pckt
{
    float gen_time;
    int node_id;
    bool last; 
    float end_time;
    int seq;
};

int main() {
    array<list<pckt>, 50> nodelist;
    array<list<pckt>, 25> APlist;

    list<pckt>::iteratot it1; 

    for(int i=0; i < 25; ++i) {
        it1= APlist[i].begin();

        while (it1 !=APlist[i].end()) {
            APlist[i].erase (it1);
            it1++;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Calling `erase` on that iterator invalidates it. Thus, you can't use it again without setting it to some meaningful value first.

Answer (score 1):

> Remove element of array of list type in c++

You cannot remove elements from arrays. They have a fixed size, so all you can do is modify the elements they contain.

However, looking at your code it looks like you want to remove all the elements of each of the `std::lists` container in an `std::array<std::list,N>`. To achieve this, you can simply iterate over the list and call [`std::list::clear()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/clear) on each element. Make sure not to leave any hard-wired numbers lying around: like all containers, an `std::array` knows how many elements it holds:

```
for (auto& l : APlist)
  l.clear()
```

Comment: That's the best answer. But I have been told that `l` (lowercase `L`) is a bad identifier choice because it resembles `1` (one) ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to erase all elements from the list:

```
APlist[i].erase(APlist[i].begin(), APlist[i].end());
```

Comment: You can just use `clear()`, too. Judging by the code, `APlist.clear();` is what the OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

This will be fastest:

```
for(int i=0; i < 25; ++i) {
    APlist[i].clear();
}
```

With iterators:

```
for(int i=0; i < 25; ++i) {
    it1 = APlist[i].begin();

    while (it1 != APlist[i].end()) {
        APlist[i].erase (it1);
        it1 = APlist[i].begin();
    }
}
```